# Toshiba Laptop ubuntu 12.10 recently overheats and turns off

Tags: overheating

This especially happens when I watch a video with movie player or adobe flash, it uses more than  60% of my Core i5 cpu. (thats the least, it goes up after that)

In windows when I watch the same movie or flash video, it is about 20% cpu usage.

I have tried many those power managerment things in the Ubuntu Wiki
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement and they did not help.

My laptops is Toshiba Sattelite P745 - Core i5 6GB Ram

Comment: If you ask me, an overheating laptop is a hardware failure, not a software one, but does the Flash CPU issue persist if you use Chrome instead of Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying thermald, this will actively monitor hot thermal zones and will try various methods to try and cool a machine.

Install with:

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

For more details, consult the kernel team [thermald](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues) reference guide.